# Cambiar clave primaria a traves de una interfaz web hecha por PDO

Tags: php, pdo

He creado una base de datos con 7 tablas, entre ellas todas tienen relación.

En dicha interfaz web necesito modificar todos los registros de la tabla incluido el campo de la clave primaria, pero nunca soy capaz de editarlo y cuando me acerco a ello me dice que esta duplicado.

Adjunto un enlace de mega con mi sql y mis php donde tengo todo para poder modificarlo o nose como quereis que os lo pase.

https://mega.nz/#!3NZjzIYR!dFqK-HNp-EIj-zGLB4tAbZWIIYVv8aegu8pbJJwOBRE

---

Este es el código:

Index.php

```
    <?php
require_once 'alumno.entidad.php';
require_once 'alumno.model.php';

// Logica
$alm = new Categoria();
$model = new CategoriaModel();

if(isset($_REQUEST['action']))
{
    switch($_REQUEST['action'])
    {
        case 'actualizar':

            // Recupero el acronimo del campo hidden

            $alm->__SET('acronimo',   $_REQUEST['acronimo']);
            $alm->__SET('categoria',  $_REQUEST['categoria']);

            $update_results = $model->Actualizar($alm);
            header('Location: index.php');
            break;

        case 'registrar':
            $alm->__SET('acronimo',  $_REQUEST['acronimo']);
            $alm->__SET('categoria', $_REQUEST['categoria']);

            $model->Registrar($alm);
            header('Location: index.php');
            break;

       case 'eliminar':
            $model->Eliminar($_REQUEST['acronimo']);
            header('Location: index.php');
            break;

        case 'editar':
            // Recupero los datos por el acronimo
            // $obj_categoria es un objeto del tipo Categoria
            $obj_categoria = $model->Obtener($_REQUEST['acronimo']);
            break;
        default: 
            // MENSAJE 404 PARA CUANDO LA ACCION NO ES VALIDA
            header('HTTP/1.0: 404 Not Found');
            die('<h1>404 Page Not Found</h1>');
    }
} 

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <title>Anexsoft</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
    </head>
    <body style="padding:15px;">

        <div class="table table-striped">
            <div class="pure-u-1-12">

                <form action="?action=<?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? 'actualizar' : 'registrar'; ?>" method="POST" class="pure-form pure-form-stacked" style="margin-bottom:30px;">
                    <input type="hidden" name="acronimo" value="<?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? $obj_categoria->__GET('acronimo') : ''; ?>" />

                    <table style="width:500px;">
                        <tr>
                            <th style="text-align:left;">Acronimo</th>
                            <td><input type="text" name="acronimo"  value="<?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? $obj_categoria->__GET('acronimo') : ''; ?>" style="width:100%;" required /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th style="text-align:left;">Categoria</th>
                            <td><input type="text" name="categoria"  value="<?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? $obj_categoria->__GET('categoria') : ''; ?>" style="width:100%;" required/></td>
                            <td colspan="2">
                                 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </form>

                <table class="pure-table pure-table-horizontal">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th style="text-align:left;">Acronimo</th>
                            <th style="text-align:left;">Categoria</th>

                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <?php foreach($model->Listar() as $r): ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $r->__GET('acronimo'); ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $r->__GET('categoria'); ?></td>

                            <td>
                                <a href="?action=editar&acronimo=<?php echo $r->acronimo; ?>">Editar</a>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <a href="?action=eliminar&acronimo=<?php echo $r->acronimo; ?>">Eliminar</a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </table>

            </div>
        </div>
          <script>js/jquery.js</script>
          <script>js/bootstrap.min.js</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

alumno.entidad.php

```
<?php
class Categoria
{
    private $acronimo;
    private $categoria;

    public function __GET($k){ return $this->$k; }
    public function __SET($k, $v){ return $this->$k = $v; }
}


alumno.model.php

<?php
class CategoriaModel
{
    private $pdo;

    public function __CONSTRUCT()
    {
        try
        {
            $this->pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=deimos1', 'root', '');
            $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    public function Listar()
    {
        try
        {
            $result = array();

            $stm = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM categoria");
            $stm->execute();

            foreach($stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ) as $r)
            {
                $alm = new Categoria();

                $alm->__SET('acronimo', $r->acronimo);
                $alm->__SET('categoria', $r->categoria);
                $result[] = $alm;
            }

            return $result;
        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    public function Obtener($acronimo)
    {
        try
        {
            $stm = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM categoria WHERE acronimo = ?");

            $stm->execute(array($acronimo));
            $r = $stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

            $alm = new Categoria();

            $alm->__SET('acronimo', $r->acronimo);
            $alm->__SET('categoria', $r->categoria);

            return $alm;
        } catch (Exception $e)
        {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    public function Eliminar($acronimo)
    {
        try
        {
            $stm = $this->pdo
                      ->prepare("DELETE FROM categoria WHERE acronimo = ?");

            $stm->execute(array($acronimo));
        } catch (Exception $e)
        {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    // ##############################################################################################
    // CAMBIOS REALIZADOS
    // - USO DE PARAMETROS NOMBRADOS EN EN METODO .execute()
    // ##############################################################################################       
    public function Actualizar(Categoria $data)
    {
        try
        {
            $sql = "UPDATE categoria SET acronimo =:acronimo, categoria =:categoria WHERE acronimo=acronimo";

            return $this->pdo->prepare($sql)
                 ->execute(
                    array(
                        ':acronimo' => $data->__GET('acronimo'),
                        ':categoria' => $data->__GET('categoria')
                    )
                );
        } catch (Exception $e)
        {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    // ##############################################################################################

    public function Registrar(Categoria $data)
    {
        try
        {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO categoria (acronimo,categoria)
                VALUES (?, ?)";

        $this->pdo->prepare($sql)
             ->execute(
            array(
                $data->__GET('acronimo'),
                $data->__GET('categoria')
                )
            );
        } catch (Exception $e)
        {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Por favor ingresa el código en tu pregunta. Piensa que si en un futuro el enlace que has puesto deja de funcionar esta consulta que has hecho ya no podría revisarse por nadie.

Comment: como puedo ingresar codigo?

Comment: Puedes revisar el tour de iniciación para ver cómo funciona el sitio: http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: O este otra donde se indica cómo formular una pregunta correctamente: http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask